# Is there a typesafe alternative to String.format(...)

Tags: java, string

For composing error, logging or any other `String` messages the `String.format(...)` method can be used. Unfortunately this method isn't type safe, hence the follwoing source will throw an `IllegalFormatException`

```
String s = String.format("My message has %d characters !", "30");
```

Is there any other alternative for composing such messages, except of the `StringBuilder` class.

*My personal opinion is that the composed message gets harder to read by using a StringBuilder instance.*

Comment: Consider using a static analysis tool like [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#VA_FORMAT_STRING_BAD_ARGUMENT).

Comment: With Scala you can have this using macros: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#a_complete_example though it probably would not work from Java.

Comment: Check out my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769455/java-string-format-compile-time-error-checking-and-safer-alternative - it still is a slight work in progress

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `String.format()` with only the %s format specifier is effectively typesafe (type opaque might be a better term) since every object will implement a `toString()` method, and even null objects are handled.

Of course, you have little control over the actual format of the string if you are not implementing`toString()`...